# Getting substring value in Chef ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I have a string that has the following value:

```
ucp-1.1.0_dtr-2.0.0
```

I am trying to fetch only `1.1.0` from the string.  I am using the following code but it doesn't seem to work

```
substring = ucp-1.1.0_dtr-2.0.0.gsub('ucp-','')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String's [`[]`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) and a simple regex will do it:

```
'ucp-1.1.0_dtr-2.0.0'[/[\d.]+/] # => "1.1.0"
```

This works because the search will stop as soon as it matches, so the first occurrence wins resulting in `1.1.0`.

If you wanted the second/last occurrence then adding `$` tells the regex engine to only look at the end of the line for the matching pattern:

```
'ucp-1.1.0_dtr-2.0.0'[/[\d.]+$/] # => "2.0.0"
```

The [Regexp documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Regexp.html) covers all this.

Answer (score 0):

`substring = "ucp-1.1.0_dtr-2.0.0".gsub('ucp-','').split("_").first` untried.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (verified):

`"ucp-1.1.0_dtr-2.0.0".match(/^.-(.)_.-.$/)[1]`

Answer (score 0):

using regex with ruby string methods you can achieve this..

`"ucp-1.1.0_dtr-2.0.0"`

```
version = "ucp-1.1.0_dtr-2.0.0".scan(/[0-9_]/).join(".").split("_").first.slice(0..-2)
```

Or with your code you can try this..

```
substring = "ucp-1.1.0_dtr-2.0.0".gsub('ucp-','').split("_").first
```